How to split a column into two columns to separate two values in a cell when some cells don't contain two values to split using dplyr in R
Issue
I want to split a column named 'Date' in my data frame into two columns called 'Date' and 'Survey_Number'
The column 'Date' either contains one date '08/04/2012' or a date and survey number '24/04/2024 [S2]' (see below).
I can split the cell using dplyr (code below); however, some cells don't contain two values to split, and I'm finding the date and survey number tend to be altered. Additionally, if only one survey took place that day, the survey number associated with this date would be zero in the new column  'Survey_Number'.
I've tried using the separate function with dplyr and the str_split_fixed function with stringr.
What can I try next?
R-Code
#Split the cell 'Date'to create two columns called 'Date' and 'Survey Number'

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Split name column into Date and Survey_Number

Df <- Df %>% separate(Date, c('Date', 'Survey_Number'))
Df

Altered Dates and Survey Numbers
  Df$Survey_Number
      [1] "01" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "03" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04" "04"
     [28] "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" "05" 

  Df$Date
  [1] "08" "06" "07" "12" "13" "14" "15" "20" "22" "23" "08" "15" "15" "16" "16" "20" "21" "21" "23" "24" "24" "27" "28" "29" "29" "29" "30"
 [28] "02" "03" "03" "04" "04" "05" "05" "05" "08" "09" "10" "13" "23" "26" "26" "27" 

Expected Output

Data frame
 structure(list(Survey_No = 1:20, Date = c("08/01/2012", "06/02/2012", 
    "07/02/2012", "12/02/2012", "13/02/2012", "14/02/2012", "15/02/2012", 
    "20/02/2012", "22/02/2012", "23/03/2012", "08/04/2012", "15/04/2012 [S1]", 
    "15/04/2012 [S2]", "16/04/2012 [S1]", "16/04/2012 [S2]", "20/04/2012", 
    "21/04/2012 [S1]", "21/04/2012 [S2]", "23/04/2012", "24/04/2024 [S1]"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")


Please reduce your example to a small one. Display expected output.

It looks like you need sep = " "  and fill = "right" options in your separate() statement.

Thanks for your suggestion! Like this: Df <- Df %>% separate(Date, c('Date', 'Survey_Number', fill = "right", sep = " ")). I tried this version of the code and the new Survey_Number column was filled with 'NA's'. I'm not an expert, I really appreciate your help.

That are levels of a factor variable! Not actual data. It appears you have misspecified something in a previous step! I had a look on your recent questions. You are running an xy-problem: https://xyproblem.info/

@Friede There are 20 rows of data in the example, it just has ALL the factor levels from the original dataset.

Try with tidyr::separate_wider_delim(Df, Date, delim = " ", names = c("Date", "Survey_Number"), too_few = "align_start") (having Date as a factor should not make a difference here)

@AliceHobbs Your reproducible example is very long because even though you only exported 20 rows of data, you exported all factor levels (including ones that were no longer present in the data). Essentially you have accidentally given us all of the possible values that column can have, even though you only gave us 20 rows of data. I would suggest editing your post to replace your long example with something like the first line of my answer that sets "df", so you don't accidentally post all of your data on the internet.

@TiredSquirrel Oh my gosh! Thank you for letting me know about the data. That was a complete accident and I really did appreciate that you old me. Corrected! Phew! Thank you so much for your answer

You can do it with gsub() which will search/replace exactly the pattern in your text you tell it to look for.
Here's an example:
df <- data.frame(Survey_No=1:20,Date=as.factor(c('08/01/2012','06/02/2012','07/02/2012',
          '12/02/2012','13/02/2012','14/02/2012','15/02/2012','20/02/2012','22/02/2012',
          '23/03/2012','08/04/2012','15/04/2012 [S1]','15/04/2012 [S2]','16/04/2012 [S1]',
          '16/04/2012 [S2]','20/04/2012','21/04/2012 [S1]','21/04/2012 [S2]','23/04/2012',
          '24/04/2024 [S1]')))

df$Date <- as.character(df$Date) # Later steps will treat date as a character, convert it from a factor
df$date_only <- gsub('\\s.*','',df$Date)
df$survnum_only <- ifelse(grepl('\\s',df$Date),gsub('.*\\s','',df$Date),NA)

The line df$date_only <- gsub('\\s.*','',df$Date) will match a space (\\s) and any characters that come after it (.*) and replace them with nothing, giving you a date-only column.
The line df$survnum_only <- ifelse(grepl('\\s',df$Date),gsub('.*\\s','',df$Date),NA) first checks if df$Date contains a space (grepl('\\s',df$Date)) -- if it doesn't, it sets survnum_only to NA. In rows where df$Date does contain a space, it uses gsub('.*\\s','',df$Date) to remove any characters before the space plus the space itself (.*\\s).
Before doing any of that, it converts the Date variable from a factor (the data type it had in your original example) to a character variable, to make sure that functions that expect a character variable will be able to process it correctly.

In base, you can do
lapply(l<-strsplit(as.character(X$Date), " "), `length<-`, max(lengths(l))) |>
  do.call(what="rbind") |> as.data.frame() |>
  transform(V1=as.Date(V1, "%d/%m/%Y"), V2=gsub("\\[|\\]", "", V2)) |>
  setNames(c("Date", "Survey_Number")) # cosmetics 

giving
         Date Survey_Number
1  2012-01-08          <NA>
2  2012-02-06          <NA>
3  2012-02-07          <NA>
4  2012-02-12          <NA>
5  2012-02-13          <NA>
6  2012-02-14          <NA>
7  2012-02-15          <NA>
8  2012-02-20          <NA>
9  2012-02-22          <NA>
10 2012-03-23          <NA>
11 2012-04-08          <NA>
12 2012-04-15            S1
13 2012-04-15            S2
14 2012-04-16            S1
15 2012-04-16            S2
16 2012-04-20          <NA>
17 2012-04-21            S1
18 2012-04-21            S2
19 2012-04-23          <NA>
20 2024-04-24            S1

where X is your data and l an intermediate object. However, I think there might me a data handling issue in a previous step.
